# How to add cancel order on customer account page magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to add cancel order functionality on myaccount page of customers so lease do the needful

[image]

please do the needful

Comment: No i want programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

Create a controller file

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Cancelorder;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $_order;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
        array $data = [])
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_order = $order;
        return parent::__construct($context,$data);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('orderid');
        $order = $this->_order->load($orderId);
        if($order->canCancel()){
            $order->cancel();
            $order->save();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Order has been canceled successfully.'));
        } else {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Order cannot be canceled.'));
        }
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

Now override `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/recent.phtml` file at `app/design/frontend/your_vendor/your_theme/Magento_Sales/templates/order/recent.phtml` and add below code in this file.

```
<?php if($_order->canCancel()) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('module/cancelorder/index').'?orderid='.$_order->getEntityId(); ?>">Cancel Order</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: For Order cancel email; which event can be used. This is not working `order_cancel_after`

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy Magento doesn't send any cancellation email. You have to create your custom email function for this.

Comment: Magento sends an email on order status update. Are you talking about that?

Comment: I need to send email when an order is cancelled from customer's side. I have developed custom module where customer can cancel order, but could not find event which sends email. `order_cancel_after` is not working although when an order is cancelled

Comment: You have to create your custom functionality for sending the email. Try to use plugin on cacel order function.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy can you tell me about that extension step by step how have you created that extension.